# Frame width is not the full screen width

Tags: swift, interface-builder, uistackview

I'm adding a gradient to a view and it's [cutting off the width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMuNb.png) on one side.

My code for adding the gradient is

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = fadeView.frame
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.mainColor().cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]

fadeView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

The `fadeView` is inside of a vertical `stackView`, inside of a `view` inside of a `scrollView`, all of which have horizontal constraints on the left and right of 0, not constraining to margins.

The frame width for the `fadeView` (and all other views other than the main view) is 320, but that might just be because of the device I'm testing on. The width of the screen is actually 375.

What's causing it to cut off like this?

Comment: have you tried `gradientLayer.frame = fadeView.bounds`?

Comment: @Malik same results. I forgot I did that one first.

Comment: is this code in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: It's called from `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Try moving it to `viewDidAppear`

Comment: If you're adding the gradient in the custom UIView class, you need to set the frame in the drawRect method. It seems that your frame was not updated in the time you're setting it to the gradient layer

Comment: That's what I figure as well... that's why I asked him to move it to `viewDidAppear` to confirm that theory

Comment: Moving it to `viewDidAppear` did take care of the sizing, but now there is a noticable delay before it appears. Is this because my code in `viewDidLoad` takes too much processing, or because `viewDidAppear` won't be called until the layout appears?

Comment: You should not add the whole implementation to the viewDidAppear. Make an instance of the gradient outside the methods. Add it as a sub view inside the viewDidLoad() (also set colors here) and set it's frame in the view controller viewWillAppear method or if it will not make a fit, then in the viewDidLayoutSubviews() method

Comment: @Woof Thanks, that took care of it!

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
 gradientLayer.frame = fadeView.frame
```

to

```
gradientLayer.frame = fadeView.bounds
```

Comment: Same result. The solution is in the comments to the post.